# How to set a Color for Typed Text in an Iframe in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, text, colors, editor

I'm using an Iframe in my rich text editor that works by execCommand functions. Right now I can change the color of any existing text in the Iframe, but I cannot get IE to set the color chosen as the color to be used when the next text is typed.

At first, I thought it was simply a focus issue, but when I re-focused the result was the same. Focusing solved the issue completely in FF, but IE will type in black when it re-focuses.

What can I do so the next text that's typed is set to be a certain color?

Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Comment: see this link http://coursesweb.net/javascript/get-modify-content-iframe_t

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see how that's useful...my page already incorporates most of that. The problem isn't that I can't change text color, it's how to do it for the next text that's typed that's the problem. I imagine some sort of listening event might be required.